# How to make Phproxy work over https

Tags: php, https, proxy

I'm using [phproxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/) and want to allow https sites to work. Is it possible?
PHProxy is a php application for bypassing blocked sites by redirecting traffic through hosted website.
It works good in non secure websites but can't open HTTPS sites.

Comment: To whom vote for close: why? please explain your reason

Comment: This vote I can't tell you, as I didn't cast it, but in the end: If you want to edit the source of phproxy your question is much to broad. If you want to know how to use the app it is offtopic.

Comment: It's much more complicated to proxy `https://` connections because the proxy server must first create a tunnel to the destination server using the HTTP `CONNECT` method and then proxy encrypted data between you and the endpoint server. This isn't something you can do external to the phproxy code -- it has to happen internally and it's unlikely given your question that phproxy is doing this.